# Laravel - Prevent form resubmission on refresh

Tags: forms, laravel

How can I prevent my form from resubmitting when I refresh the page. Solutions I've found suggest a redirection, which I am using.

The form in view **admin.enrollform.blade.php**:

```
    <form id="enrollform" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post"
      enctype="multipart/form-data"
      action="{{route('storeStudent', ['site' => $site->site_url, 'lang' => $lang] )}}">
      <input type="visible" name="_token" id="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
      ...
    </form>
```

The laravel controller:

```
public function store(Request $request, $site, $lang = null)
{

    ....

    return view('admin.enrollform', [
        'message'       => $message
    ]);
}
```

If successful, the controller returns a view, which points to the same page. So the same page is loaded again, with a message. And the form is empty.

However if I click refresh at this point, the form submits again. I would like for it just refresh the page, with or without the message it had received from the controller.

Is there any way for me to use the CSRF token to validate this? From what I understand the CSRF token only validates if the session is valid, and has nothing to do with the form itself.

Thanks.

Comment: The only requests that should return a view are `GET` requests. a `POST` request (or `PATCH` etc.) should *always* return a redirect. Always. The Laravel validation documentation talks about how the validation system works with redirects, take a look at that for an idea of how standard form submission works in Laravel :) https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation

Comment: Following your advice worked. I used return Redirect::route('enrollStudent')->with(['message' => $message]). Do you know why this does not work:  Redirect::route('enrollStudent', ['message' => $message])?

Comment: The `with` method sets the values as flash data: session data available for the next request only, then it's cleared. The second example you've provided is setting the values as request parameters, so the latter will produce `https://example.com/{enrollStudent}?message={$message}` which is not what you're looking for as Laravel validation uses session data :-)

Comment: Hmm that makes sense. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use return `back()`

```
return back()->with(['message' => $message]);
```

Comment: I think you meant return back()->with(['message' => $message]); ?

Comment: Redirect works better since I can return other request parameters with it.

Comment: What conditional should I use to use this return besides my normal return.